# is it Possible to name a folder with a name that is more than 256 characters?

Tags: windows, vba, excel

I have a small issue to be dealt with, i need to create a folder hierarchy like A/B/C/D where each is a folder with foldername more than 256 characters. i know that windows allows only 256 characters at max, but i think somebody over here can help me in this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need such long folder names?

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/210631

Comment: I think it is possible to get around the restriction by starting the path with `\\\` but I question the wisdom of attempting it. At the very least a lot of stuff is going to break.

Comment: @DavidRobinson Am just to explore it and find if this is possible. is there a way of doing it! can you afford your views.

Comment: @Mark i will try your suggestion, thanks.

Comment: None of the programming language will help us do this, because windows explorer will not allow us do so, for instance in VBA i get "path not found" error when i tried to create a folder with absolute path of length more than 256 characters. if this is right is there any other way to disable windows restrictions?!? 

Any discussions are welcomed. :)

Comment: @mark i could not figure out it exactly how and where to use the \\ could you please give an example...

Comment: This is not possible because the file system does not support path components larger than 255 characters.

Comment: @Luke: actually the file system does have support for long names (see the answer below) but the ANSI version of the Win32 API does not.  Neither do many of the shell tools.  It is likely that VBA doesn't either, so I think the OP is out of luck.

Comment: You will probably need to use a more native programming language to do this.  I doubt that VBA supports it.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: I mean individual path components (e.g. a single folder or file name) cannot exceed 255 characters, which I believe is what the question is about.  He wants to do "A\B\C\D" where A, B, C, and D are each individually longer than 255 characters.

Comment: @Luke: checking the documentation, you're absolutely right.  I didn't realize that the individual component limitation still applied.

Answer (score 1):

I found this answer, I think it answers your question..

> In fact the limit on path strings is 260 characters. The underlying OS, these days, can support much longer path names, up to [32,767 characters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28VS.85%29.aspx#maxpath). In order to name a path with a long name you need to use the magic \?\ prefix, and use the Unicode version of the API.
>
> However, many tools don't support such long names. A classic example
>   of such a tool is Explorer which won't let you create objects with
>   names longer than 260 characters. Because of this I strongly advise
>   you to avoid creating such long names—doing so will save you much
>   heartache in the long run.
>
> [Mark Ransom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5987/mark-ransom)

Comment: "I found this answer" - an attribution would be nice.

Comment: oops.. knew i forgot something.. Sorry!

Comment: Thanks for your response, but 
aaaaaaaa......(256)a/ bbbb....(256)b will make the filename length of bbb....b to be more than 512. am i right?!? Am to create this hierarchy in VBA, can you please help me out